# How to reference a theme image in a stylesheet?

Tags: images, css, urls

I have a global element as part of my theme and I need to reference and image as a background image. I need the URL to the image. I assume that it's bad practice to hard-code the URL and that the URL needs to be relative to the theme location. What is the recommended way of referencing an image within a stylesheet?

Comment: Where is the image location or it is to be uploaded?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on your image and stylesheet location.

But this is the syntax:

```
.theme-image {
  background-image: url('../images/header-img.jpg');
}
```

The above code is for the structure

```
wp-content
 - themes
  - your-theme 
    - images
     - header-img.jpg
    - css
     - style.css
```

You are making the browser come one directory before and search for images directory.

Comment: Not working for me, i have same structure

Comment: @HidaytRahman Do you have a demo of it?

Comment: Yep, It's working, it was not working due to some silly mistake, thanks :)

Comment: What could be that silly mistake? ;)

Comment: I had white-space in name of the image which i was inserting :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the relativity of the URL.
I mean, when openening a categoryoverview from third or deeper child-categories like this:

`-nature`
`--animals`
`---wolves >>>3rd level`
`--birds`

The URL for wolves would become like:
/category/nature/animals/wolves/
Therefore the imagelocation is one directory-level before and doesn't show up.

So I tried this and it worked:

```css
.sidebar-row .widget {
  background-image: url("../../../../wp-content/uploads/.../image.webp");
  background-image: url("../../../../../wp-content/uploads/.../image.webp");
  background-image: url("../../../../../../wp-content/uploads/.../image.webp");
}
```

Images on incorrect locations will be ignored, the one on the correct location will show up.

BTW: I'm using the "Simple CSS"-plugin to change the layout for my site.

Comment: Whilst that's a neat solution your browser will have to make up to three requests for the image until it discovers the correct one. I'd prefer another way of solving this.

Answer (score -2):

For WordPress, it should be something like this:

```
   background:url('../wp-content/themes/yourtheme/images/social-icons-v2-opt.png');
```

**For Child Theme**

```
   background:url('../wp-content/themes/yourtheme-child/images/social-icons-v2-opt.png');
```

Comment: The directories `wp-content` and `themes` can be renamed. Do NOT use these names in your coded.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Yeah, this is not exactly the code. That is why I stated "It is something like this".